# use jquery to search for a word and crossline it or replace it with another word

Tags: jquery

so i couldn't find how to do it...

oh, yeah... i wanted it to be jquery so i will be able to do it on all but the last one

this is my problem too

Comment: Why would you want to use jQuery for that? JavaScript can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, this:

```
var search = $('body').html();
search = search.replace(/Phrase/g, function($1){
    return('<span style="text-decoration: line-through">' + $1 + '</span>');
});


$('body').html(search);
```

should do it. This example would strikeout every appearance of "Phrase" in the whole body.

Executing it on the document body is maybe a bad example.
I would recommend to execute it on a specific element.

Comment: Also this will break if your "phrase" can be in your HTML markup like a tag name, part of a CSS property, part of some JavaScript, etc.

Comment: what about not crossing the last one?

and for some reason the crossline height is too much... can it be changes?